# Java support for conditional lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

In the following let's say zip codes I am trying to exclude the `33333-` from the result.
I do:

```
String zip = "11111 22222 33333- 44444-4444";
String regex = "\\d{5}(?(?=-)-\\d{4})";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(zip);
while (matcher.find()) { 
   System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());     
}
```

Expect to get:

```
Found:  11111  
Found:  22222  
Found:  44444-4444
```

**I am trying to enforce format of:

5 digits optionally followed by a - and 4 digits. 5 digits with just a - (hyphen) is not wanted**

I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 7
\d{5}(?(?=-)(-\d{4}))
       ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
```

Am I not using the conditional lookahead correctly?

Comment: Do you want the last one to match as `44444-4444` or just `44444`?

Comment: I want to get `11111` `22222` `44444-4444` but not the `33333-`.The conditional look ahead I thought would not include `33333-`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To capture all numbers except 33333 use this code:

```
String zip = "11111 22222 33333- 44444-4444";
String regex = "\\d{5}(?=(-\\d{4}|\\s|$))(-\\d{4})?";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(zip);
while(m.find())
    System.out.printf("Macthed: [%s]%n", m.group(1));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Macthed: [11111]
Macthed: [22222]
Macthed: [44444-4444]
```

**Explanation:** This RegEx is using lookahead that itself is like a condition, which means match 5 digit number which must be followed by - and 4 digits OR a space OR end of string and then it is optionally matching a text - and 4 digits.

The reason why your original RegEx is throwing exception because there is a syntax error in `?:(?=-)` part of your RegEx.

Comment: My main problem is why I get the exception.I want to extract the numbers adhering a specified format using conditionals.

Comment: Actually you can fix exception in your regex by using `"\\d{5}(?:(?=-)-\\d{4})"` however that will **only capture** `44444-4444`

Comment: But does this mean that conditional regular expression based on look ahead does not work in Java?Otherwise what is the correct syntax?

Comment: I don't understand your regex.`(?=(-\\d{4}|\\s|$))` means lookahead for a hyphen followed by 4 digits OR empty space OR end of string?Where is the conditional here?Sorry, is my initial regex all wrong?

Comment: In the same sentence you wrote you didn't understand my regex and then you interpreted it right. It does exactly what your intent is that **5 digits optionally followed by a - and 4 digits. 5 digits with just a - (hyphen) is not wanted**. Regarding your RegEx: yes it will definitely not compile as I mentioned earlier to you .

Comment: I mean it is a lookahead and not a conditional.How does it work if it is not a conditional?

Comment: Actually it is using lookahead that itself is like a condition. This RegEx means match 5 digit number which must be followed by `- and 4 digits OR a space OR end of string` and then it is optionally matching a text `- and 4 digits`.

Comment: Ok.+1.If you could please update your answer explaining that the exception is caused by wrong syntax and also when a lookahead is also a conditional of what follows (I got it?) or a reference to this, I will gladly mark your answer as accepted.Thanks

Comment: Thanks, explanation added in the answer.

Comment: The Op is right and its regex is not wrong. The fact is that the java engine do not support If-Then-Else Conditionals expression. http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: another reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072756/does-java-support-if-then-else-regexp-constructsperl-constructs

Answer (score 0):

You'r missing a colon after `(?`, i.e. use this regex (non-Java-String): `\d{5}(?:(?=-)-\d{4})`.

However, this might still not produce the result you want. Please post some example input and required output.

Comment: This produces only 44444-4444.I was expecting `11111` `22222` `44444-4444`.So my regex (I thought) would match the first 5 digits and the conditional lookahead would include also `44444-4444` but not `33333-` since the conditinal look ahead would be false

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear to me. I suppose you are looking for:

```
String st = "11111 22222 33333- 44444-4444";
String pattern = "\\d+(- )";
String res  = st.replaceAll(pattern,"");
System.out.println(res);
```

Output = `11111 22222 44444-4444`

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{5}(?!-\s)(?:-\d{4})?)
```

hence:

```
String regex = "(\\d{5}(?!-\\s)(?:-\\d{4})?)";`
```