# Java Regex Throwing Error for If-Then-Else

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to run this regular expression statement in Java. It should return false because the regex mandates there should only be an O,P,L, or H at the eighth position if there is an "A" in the third position.

```
System.out.println("TLN7HRNO".matches("[-LBQTHWROMSNT](0MIL|[LBCDGJKMNPQSTUVWXYZ][NA][0137CUVRT][PCBMVWTHKNDG])(NR|RR)(?(?<=A[A-Z0-9]{4})[OPLH]|$)"));
```

However, Java is not liking the IF-THEN-ELSE statement even though my regex editor worked just fine with it.

Does Java have a different implementation for IF-THEN-ELSE or does it just not support it all all.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 81
...[PCBMVWTHKNDG])(NR|RR)(?(?<=A[A-Z0-9]{4})[OPLH]|$)
                           ^                                                 
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.matches(Unknown Source)
at com.swa.rm.pricing.PFCLInterface.launchCLInterface(PFCLInterface.java:45)
at com.swa.rm.pricing.PFCLInterface.main(PFCLInterface.java:24)
```

Comment: try `[-LBQTHWROMSNT](0MIL|[LBCDGJKMNPQSTUVWXYZ][NA][0137CUVRT][PCBMVWTHKNDG])(NR|RR)(?:(?<=A[A-Z0-9]{4})[OPLH]|$)`

Comment: Java's regexes are documented in the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. Any syntax that isn't listed there, isn't supported. Note that there is no (?X) (but as noted above, (?:X) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: `(?X)` and `(?:X)` are two wholly different things. OP is looking for an IFTHENELSE regex statement not a non-capturing group. @yshavit look here:http://regex101.com/r/qC1jJ3/1

Comment: The canonical Q: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8072756/1296806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your `Pattern`, as mentioned in the comments. Here's a walk-through:

```
[-LBQTHWROMSNT](0MIL|[LBCDGJKMNPQSTUVWXYZ][NA][0137CUVRT][PCBMVWTHKNDG])(NR|RR)(?(?<=A[A-Z0-9]{4})[OPLH]|$)
```

Firstly, there's abundance in your character classes. `[-LBQTHWROMSNT]` can be shortened to `[-L-OBQ-THW]`; `[LBCDGJKMNPQSTUVWXYZ]` use a range at the last character section to become `[LBCDGJKMNPQS-Z]`. `(NR|RR)` can be changed to `([NR]R)` as `|` alternation follows a **backtracking** nature and `[]` lists are optimal and well-suited for usages like these.

The pattern syntax error is caused by `(?(?<=`. This is because in regex patterns, `(?` is a special pattern syntax. The next character following `?` will determine the nature of this group, and it **must** form a special syntax group - otherwise `?` becomes a quantifier and it fails to follow a quantifiable token.
In this case, your pattern failed to compile as `(?(` is no accepted syntax in Java.

You might have meant to use a **non-capturing group** instead. `->` `(?: )`

**Read more:**

- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [Pattern (Java Platform SE 7) documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)