# Java Regex mimicking if-else for numbers

Tags: java, regex

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079647/3040381) as a guide to attempt to emulate an if-else Java regex, I came up with: 
`[0-2]?(?:(?<=2)(?![6-9])|(?<!2)(?=[0-9]))` to do the following:

An optional digit between 0-2 inclusive as the leftmost digit; However, if the first digit is a 2, then the next digit to the right can be maximum 5. If it is a 0 or 1, or left blank, then 0-9 is valid. I am trying to ultimately end up allowing a user to only write the numbers 0-255.

Testing the regular expression on both Regex101 as well as javac doesn't work on test cases, despite the Regex101 explanation being congruent with what I want.

When I test the regex:

`System.out.println("0".matches("[0-2]?(?:(?<=2)(?![6-9])|(?<!2)(?=[0-9]))"));` ---> false

`System.out.println("2".matches("[0-2]?(?:(?<=2)(?![6-9])|(?<!2)(?=[0-9]))"));` ----> true

`System.out.println("25".matches("[0-2]?(?:(?<=2)(?![6-9])|(?<!2)(?=[0-9]))"));` ----> false

`System.out.println("22".matches("[0-2]?(?:(?<=2)(?![6-9])|(?<!2)(?=[0-9]))"));` ----> false

`System.out.println("1".matches("[0-2]?(?:(?<=2)(?![6-9])|(?<!2)(?=[0-9]))"));` ----> false

It appears so far, from few test cases, 2 is the only valid case that is accepted by the regex.

For reference, here is my initial regex, using if-else that limits a number to the range of 0-255: `[0-2]?(?(?<=2)[0-5]|[0-9])(?(?<=25)[0-5]|[0-9])`

Comment: explain by `doesn't work` mean and show some code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat There's no code necessary in this question; the regex covers that. And doesn't work fairly obviously means doesn't match expected strings.

Comment: With that said, though, it'd be nice to include some test cases.

Comment: @Vulcan If it works with Perl but not Java, then I suggest that some code is necessary.

Comment: @ScaryWombat In Perl, OP used an if-else. Java doesn't support conditional regexes, so OP is converting the regex to work in Java (unsuccessfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why to mimic `if` `else` for checking a range. It's just putting some patterns together.

```
^(?:[1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

- `^` start anchor
- `(?:` opens a [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) for alternation
- `[1-9]?\d` matches 0-99
- `1\d\d` matches 100-199
- `2[0-4]\d` matches 200-249
- `25[0-5]` matches 250-255
- `$` end anchor

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bX0wR6/1)

With allowing leading zeros, you can reduce it to
 [`^(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$`](https://regex101.com/r/gC4pR9/1)

Comment: It isn't exactly what I wanted, as I wanted cases such as 000 or 001 or 02 to be accepted, but I modified it by prepending: `0\d|00\d|0\d\d|`

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to only allow a range of numbers (0-255), why use regex at all? Instead, parse the string as an int and check if it falls within the range.

```
public static boolean isInRange(String input, int min, int max) {
    try {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(input);
        return val >= min && val < max;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the purpose of the exercise is to use Regex only, even if there are much easier and better ways, otherwise it'd be cheating.