# Regex to match all occurrences that begin with n characters in sequence

Tags: regex

I'm not sure if it's even possible for a regular expression to do this. Let's say I have a list of the following strings:

```
ATJFH
ABHCNEK
BKDFJEE
NCK
ABH
ABHCNE
KDJEWRT
ABHCN
EGTI
```

And I want to match all strings that begin with any number of characters for the following string: `ABHCNEK`

The matches would be:

```
ABH
ABHCN
ABHCNE
ABHCNEK
```

I tried things like `^[A][B][H][C][N][E][K]` and `^A[B[H[C[N[E[K]]]]]]`, but I can't seem to get it to work...

Can this be done in regex? If so, what would it be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206448/regular-expression-matching-any-subset-of-a-given-set Sorry, pasted wrong link in earlier comment.

Comment: That is if the order of appearance of the characters doesn't matter to you. If it does, I believe @sagarpandya82 's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest can be

```
^(?:ABHCNEK|ABHCNE|ABHCN|ABHC|ABH|AB|A)$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/6

Comment: @guruguru, choose this one

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
^[ABHCNEK]+$
```

Comment: That won't do it in order.  It would match "CKBE"

Comment: @tokamak, that is what OP wants. Read the question

Comment: Don't tell me to read the question... OP specified which strings from the example would match, "NCK" was not one of them, which your regex would match.

Comment: I don't see your point... BHCNEK isn't in the OP's example list of strings; maybe you're just messing with me now. We'll let the OP say explicitly whether the order of chars matter or not.

Comment: lol settle dooown.  :)  As per the title of this post: "REGEX to match all occurrences that begin with n characters in sequence".  So "in sequence" is key, but I didn't repeat that detail in the post body.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you want to use it, but one option doesn't require regex.  Loop through the various strings and check for a match within your test string:

```js
var strings = ['ATJFH', 'ABHCNEK', 'BKDFJEE', 'NCK', 'ABH', 'ABHCNE', 'KDJEWRT', 'ABHCN', 'EGTI'];

var test = 'ABHCNEK';

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  if (test.match(strings[i])) {
    console.log(strings[i]);
  }
}
```

This returns:

ABHCNEK
ABH
ABHCNE
ABHCN